# Using the Rally API to pull user profile

Tags: rally

I am trying to use the Rally web service API to get some data. Code as blow. On IE it will pop out a login window, after entry login name and password, I am about to get some data. But when I use chrome, it response 401, not sure what I missing. I know there is SDK available, but due to some limitation, not able to use it. Any suggestions please?

```
var url = https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/users;
 $.ajax({
   url: url,
   type: 'GET',
   heards: { zsessionid: apiKey },
   success: function(json) { 
     console.log(JSON.stringify(json));
     }
   },
   error: function( req, status, err ) { console.log( 'something went wrong', status, err );
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd love to know more about why you can't use the SDK.  Anyway, in this case your config likely needs headers instead of heards to pass the api key.

Comment: I did try but still got 401     headers: {
        'Authorization':'Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'Content-Type':'application/json'
    },